# KillTimer - Destroy inadvertently a timer of another process

Tags: winapi, timer

Should **KillTimer** be called by the same process of the specified timer?

Comment: @user1 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644903%28v=vs.85%29.aspx nothing about destroying timer of another process.

Comment: The `SetTimer` docs are clear that `hWnd` must belong to the calling thread. It seems extremely likely that the same restriction would apply to `KillTimer`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the term "inadvertently" is supposed to mean in this context. Are you looking to "accidentally" kill the timer?

Comment: How do you suppose you could accidentally pass an HWND of a different process?

Comment: The docs are also clear that the hWnd can be null, @Jonathan. What then?

Comment: @RobKennedy If there's no window given then you are dealing with a thread timer, and then there's absolutely no doubt that they are thread-specific.

Comment: @JerryDodge thank you. but my solution is not completed yet. the ID  that generated randomly still an issue for me. thanks again.

Comment: Oh, that wasn't clear that you still have a problem. By reading your update, it appears to explain that you've found the solution - specifically how you say "i was able to kill a timer of another process" and "The problem was..."

Comment: Wait, if you have the code for the other process, then why don't you make another method of killing the timer? For example, make your own Windows Message you can feed to it which instructs the other process to kill its own timer?

Comment: Are you just asking a hypothetical question about how `KillTimer` works, or do you have an actual problem to be solved?

Comment: @JerryDodge Actually i don't have the code of the process that create the timer i just wrote this code to explain my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `KillTimer` *should* be called by the same process as the one that called `SetTimer`. However, although the documentation is clear that the calling thread needs to own the window when calling `SetTimer`, there doesn't seem to be the same enforcement for `KillTimer`. It doesn't even say the killer needs to be the same process, let alone the same thread. Thus, what *should* happen and what *must* happen are two different things.

[Raymond Chen wrote in his blog in 2012 about killing timers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/31/10312066.aspx), and in the comments are several statements claiming that timers can only be killed from the original process. Those statements are left unchallenged, but it turns out to be easy to disprove them experimentally.

The following command-line program shows that it's possible to kill timers from other processes. Run it once with no arguments, and it creates a timer and begins printing messages with the timer ID. Pass that ID to a second invocation of the program, and that the second instance will kill the first instance's timer. It will report success, and the first instance will stop printing messages (because it's no longer receiving timer messages).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        std::istringstream in(argv[1]);
        UINT timerid;
        in >> timerid;
        if (!KillTimer(NULL, timerid)) {
            DWORD err = GetLastError();
            std::cout << "KillTimer error (" << err << ")" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "KillTimer success" << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        UINT timerid = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 1000, NULL);
        std::cout << "Get timer ID " << timerid << std::endl;
        MSG msg;
        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
            if (msg.message == WM_TIMER) {
                std::cout << "Got WM_TIMER " << msg.wParam << std::endl;
            }
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(Processes were 32 bits running on 64-bit Windows 7 VM, compiled with Visual Studio 2015 because that's what I have. Equivalent code in any other language should be easy to replicate.)